# Changing a color of a icon from an action on an other page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am a beginner on C#, I am coding an UWP app on Visual Studio, mostly for Windows 10 platforms.

Here's my problem:
I have a navigation view on the main page, which lists a few subjects.
Clicking on one of them brings you to a page (Page1) where I have radio buttons, that changes the color of the title of this Page1.

I would like to have this color applied to the subject on the main page

Can't figure out how to do...

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the **NavigationView** in `MainPage.xaml.cs` by creating a static instance of `MainPage` and change the color.

Here is the solution:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<NavigationView x:Name="nvSample"
                x:FieldModifier="Public">
    ...
</NavigationView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public static MainPage Current;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
}
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var nav = MainPage.Current.nvSample;
    nav.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Richard, I made it :)

The Page1.xaml.cs code changed all the texts foreground in my page though, so I used this:

```
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)            
    {
        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)sender;
        {}

        if (radio != null)
        {

            String selected = radio.Tag.ToString();
            switch (selected)
            {


                default:
                case "Red":
                    Title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    MainPage.Current.Subject1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    break;`
```

Thank you again.

Now next mission for me, saving those colors after the application is closed so they stay the same when the app is lunched. If you have any advices... :)

Comment: Hi, If my answer helps you, please mark my answer. If you have other questions, you can open a new thread, This can help more people with the same problem. Thank you